# Eclipse upgrade for macOS Catalina

Tags: eclipse, macos, upgrade, macos-catalina

I have to upgrade my Eclipse IDE (currently 2019-03).  I found the upgrade instructions on the Eclipse wiki, which involve adding the URL for the latest Eclipse release to the "Available software sites" (where Eclipse checks for updates).

However, there is also now an Eclipse Installer (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer) which is labelled as "the easiest way to install AND UPDATE your Eclipse...", and includes a JRE.

I am especially concerned about my pending Eclipse upgrade given that I need to upgrade my macOS to 10.15 (i.e. Catalina). Eclipse has had many problems reported with Catalina in the past, many related to Java compatibility issues with Catalina. So I am thinking that the Eclipse Installer with the bundled JRE may be a more reliable upgrade path.  Can people report if the Eclipse 2020-09 installer builds an Eclipse IDE which seamlessly works with Catalina?

Comment: The current Eclipse works fine on Catalina. For Big Sure which has been released after the current Eclipse I would recommend to wait for Eclipse 2020-12 which will be released next week (or use a preview version of it) and which contains Java also when installing directly as `.dmg`. The Eclipse Installer cannot be used to upgrade an Eclipse that have not been installed via the Eclipse Installer. Every new OS version can break Eclipse and other applications. Therefore it is a bad idea to use older software than the operating system and you are currently two releases behind.

Comment: I don't think my original Eclipse was installed via the Eclipse Installer (is there a way to ascertain this, retrospectively?), so I guess I cannot go with the Installer.  That answers my question.    Thank you.

Comment: To update this for others, I believe the primary difference between using the Eclipse Installer to upgrade and performing an upgrade using the "Additional Software Sites" option is this:  The Eclipse Installer does not appear to update. It seems to install a fresh copy of Eclipse.  So if you really want to update, do not use the Eclipse Installer.

Comment: The Eclipse Installer uses one bundle/plugins pool for all Eclipse installation which saves disk space when having more than one Eclipse installation. And in addition, the _Advanced Mode_ makes it easy to contribute (does all required stuff: installs Eclipse, check-outs Git repositories and configure Eclipse) which can also be used in a company for internal projects.